# Find thresholds for binary classification

Tags: python

I have an array of ordered numeric values and a corresponding array of classes, in the form of yes/no. I need to find thresholds that have this criteria, quoting the paper I'm studying on:
"T is a threshold if it falls bewteen two consecutive examples that do not belong to the same class. In the special case when a group of two or more examples have the same value but belong to more than one class, then the cut points on either side of the examples are also thresholds. The examples with identical values cannot be separated."

If I understood correclty, if I have:

```
vals = [10,12, 22, 28, 28, 40, 41]
classes = ['y','y','n','y','n','y','n']
```

the thresholds must be: `[17,25,34,40.5]`

This is the code I wrote:

```
    for i in range(len(vals)-1):
        if vals[i] != vals[i+1]:
            if classes[i] != classes[i+1]:
                thresholds.append((vals[i] + vals[i+1]) / 2)
        else:
            j = i
            while vals[i] == vals[i+1]:
                i = i+1
            if j != 0:
                thresholds.append((vals[j] + vals[j-1]) / 2)
            thresholds.append((vals[i] + vals[i+1]) / 2)
```

But 1) I really don't like it and I'd like it to be more compact, 2) even if it works for the example before it's not always true, for example if I have

```
vals = [2,2,5,5,7,11,18] 
out = ['y','y','y','y','n','n','n]
```

I'd like the only threshold to be `[6]`, but this code prints also `3.5`

How can I make this prettier and more generic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**
This is the new code for now (which can be refactored further and I will post that in my next edit). I have tested it on a good number of test cases. Below is just the code, you can find the detailed code with comments and unit tests in these links:

- [Detailed Code With Comments.](https://github.com/sanjay-chivukula/stackoverflow-projects/blob/main/break-sequence/break_sequence.py)
- [Detailed Tests for this code.](https://github.com/sanjay-chivukula/stackoverflow-projects/blob/main/break-sequence/test_break_sequence.py)

**Plain code:**

```
def compress_group(vls):
    val0, lab0 = next(vls[1])
    if all(lab == lab0 for val, lab in vls[1]):
        return val0, lab0
    return val0, case2_label

vl_combined = [(v, l) for v, l in zip(values, labels)]
vl_groups = groupby(vl_combined, lambda vc: vc[0])
vl_groups = map(lambda vl_group: compress_group(vl_group), vl_groups)

thresholds = []
prev_value, prev_label = next(vl_groups)
for curr_value, curr_label in vl_groups:
    if prev_label == case2_label or curr_label != prev_label:
        threshold = (prev_value + curr_value) / 2
        thresholds.append(threshold)
    prev_value, prev_label = curr_value, curr_label

return thresholds
```

Comment: thank you! this is definetely nicer to look at. unfortunately, it doesn't work for every array (maybe I've been too vague with my examples) because it doesn't add thresholds at the borders of a section that has the same value. say, 9,13,13,15 (y,y,n,n) I'd like 11 and 14 to be added too. Any ideas how to do that? Or maybe I'm misinterpretating what the paper asks?
p.s. thank you for the note, in my code the name is different but I changed it here too make it easier to understand. I'll edit it to classes now.

Comment: I understood the logic mentioned in the paper. I will update the code in a while now.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, thank you but I can't really understand this solution? What do you mean by temp[-1][1] = 'both sides'? When I tested it on some other numbers though it didn't really work, it finds some more thresholds that should note be there. Do you have some more ideas? Sorry I'm really stuck on this

Comment: Check my new update. I have tested them for a good number of special cases. This should meet the requirements. If it still fails please give me samples to test this code on.